# Angular Databinding doesnt Work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have got a form where user will enter a name and click Next. What I want to do is that, when the user clicks Next, I want to `alert` the updated value of `$scope.name` inside `toChat` function, but  initial value is alerted, which is James.  How can I access the updated value inside angular function? I have some serious problems understanding sharing variables within AngularJs.

**js**

```
.controller('NewcontactCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope, $ionicHistory,$window) {

     $scope.name='James';
     $scope.myGoBack = function() {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
      };
     $scope.toChat = function() {
         alert($scope.name);

     };
 })
```

**html**

```
<ion-view view-title="New contact">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>

     <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
      <button class="button" ng-click="myGoBack()">
       Cancel 
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

     <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
      <button class="button" ng-click="toChat()" >
       Next
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content scroll="false" has-header="false" padding="true" >

        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" />
            </label> 
            <label class="item item-input">
                <textarea placeholder="Notes" ng-model="notes" rows="10"></textarea>
            </label> 
        </div>   
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: is it still not working with ```$scope.name```? ie. when you add ```$scope```

Comment: No the original question is with scope. This way, toChat function gets the initial value.

Comment: so what do you want to do? if user adds a different name you want to alert this? @Ozgen

Comment: yes, when the user changes the textfield I want to alert it.

Comment: see changes below, does this do what you want or does it need to say 'James' at the start? @ozgen

Comment: Exactly! How could I make a workaround?  @devqon

Comment: in your ionic ```app.js``` file, or whatever you named it you need to state that the controller is ```NewcontactCtrl``` for the relevant part of the app, it was the first part of my ```config``` when I built an ionic app. Might be a good idea to provide contents of that file in your question, will make it easier to answer @Ozgen

Comment: In routing configuration, controller is defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77326/discussion-between-paul-fitzgerald-and-ozgen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

The most relevant part in the above:

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try **2-way data binding** (i.e., form elements, ng-model) **to a primitive** (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch, ng-view and ng-include all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved. ...
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with ng-switch.
>
> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use 
>   `<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1">` rather than 
>   `<input type="text" ng-model="prop1">`.

I believe you have a directive in there somewhere (probably ion-content) that is creating a new scope where your input field is, separated from the scope where your Next button is.

To simulate this, I've used `ng-repeat` in the below snippet (but I'm repeating only once), which causes the same behaviour of splitting the scopes. If you were to use your controller code unmodified with this html, you'd reproduce the issue you're experiencing.

The solution around this is to 'use a dot (.)' when binding. Notice that I've wrapped the name within an object called 'data' on the scope, so now you refer to this as `data.name` instead of just `name`.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('NewcontactCtrl', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.repeaterTest = [1];
      $scope.data = {name: 'James'};
      $scope.toChat = function() {
        $window.alert($scope.data.name);
      };
    });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="NewcontactCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="test in repeaterTest">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="data.name" />
    </label>
    <button class="button" ng-click="toChat()">
      Next
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is fantastic!

Comment: Thanks, glad to help! The referenced article is a very useful read in its entirety, when you have the time. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to alert something similar to...
`alert($scope.name)`

Comment: Sorry, I actually used $scope , I updated my question. The problem here is different scopes are created by angular, and the button click cannot reach the child scope

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Paul Fitzgerald, points, ensure that `ng-controller="NewcontactCtrl"` is included at the top scope in HTML DOM.

Comment: This is a angular template. Do I still need to include that?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a service in order to share data within scopes

```
.controller('NewcontactCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,sharedData $ionicHistory,$window) {

     $scope.name=sharedData.Name ;
     $scope.myGoBack = function() {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
      };
     $scope.toChat = function() {
         alert(sharedData.Name);

     };
 });

app.factory('sharedData', [function () {
    var self = {};

    self.Name = "James";


    return self;
}]);
```

Comment: But when I change the texfield, I still get the old initial value which is 'James'.